# Simulation to visualize power does not predict built-in power functions

Tags: r, statistics, simulation, t-test

I built a shiny web [APP](https://sortizaburto.shinyapps.io/power_calculator/) with a nice interface to calculate sample size needed to differentiate between test groups. I wanted to build a simulation that visualizes how power works, my understanding is that power is the probability of differentiating test groups from each other when in fact these are different. Using the built in power calculator I find that I need 10 replicates to distinguish 2 samples groups when %CV =15, %Improvement = 20 and power = 80%. When I try to simulate this using random number generators I on average get a power of 40-55%. See the code below.

```
cv <- 15 #coefficient of variance is the standard deviation divided by the mean
percent_increase <- 20 #percent increase to detect
mean1 <- 40
mean2 <- mean1 + (mean1*(percent_increase/100))
sd1 <- (cv*mean1)/100 
sd2 <- (cv*mean2)/100
pooled_sd <- sqrt((sd1^2 + sd2^2)/2)
difference <- (percent_increase/100)*mean1


pwrt <- power.t.test(delta=difference,sd=sd1,power=0.8,sig.level = .05, type="two.sample", alternative = "two.sided")
print(paste("Number of replicates needed is", pwrt$n))


#Simulate sample populations and tag which samples are different from each other. 
record_test <- c()
for(i in 1:1000){
  rep_sequence <- seq(2,50, by=4)
  data_list <- list() # empty data list
  for(r in 1:length(rep_sequence)){
    d <- rnorm(rep_sequence[r], mean = mean1, sd = pooled_sd)
    d2 <- rnorm(rep_sequence[r], mean = mean2, sd = pooled_sd)
    df <- data.frame("value"=d, "sample"="Sample 1")
    df2 <- data.frame("value"=d2, "sample"="Sample 2")
    df3 <- rbind(df, df2)
    df3$rep_n <- rep_sequence[r]
    data_list[[r]] <- df3
  }

  all_data <- do.call(rbind, data_list)
  all_data_summ <- all_data %>%
    group_by(sample, rep_n) %>%
    summarise(N= n(),
              mean = mean(value),
              sd = sd(value)
    ) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    mutate(se = sd / sqrt(N),
           ci_lower = mean - qnorm(0.975)*se, 
           ci_upper = mean + qnorm(0.975)*se,
           #ci_lower = mean - qt(1 - (0.05/2), N -1)* se,
           #ci_upper = mean + qt(1 - (0.05/2), N -1)* se,
    ) 

  different_tag <- (all_data_summ %>% filter(sample == 'Sample 1') %>% select(N, ci_upper) ) %>% #Sample 1 set
    left_join(all_data_summ %>% filter(sample == 'Sample 2') %>% select(N, ci_lower), by=c("N"="N")) %>% #Sample 2 set
    rename(ci_upper_s1 = ci_upper, ci_lower_s2 = ci_lower) %>%
    mutate(different = ifelse(ci_lower_s2 > ci_upper_s1 ,'yes', 'no'))            

  all_data_summ1 <- all_data_summ %>%
    left_join(different_tag %>% select(N, different), by=c("N"="N"))

  replicate_n <- 10 #at n=10 the power should be 80%
  test_result <- all_data_summ1[all_data_summ1$rep_n == replicate_n, ]$different[[1]]
  record_test <- c(record_test, test_result)

  ggplot(all_data_summ1, aes(rep_n, mean)) +
    geom_errorbar(aes(x=rep_n, ymin=ci_lower, ymax= ci_upper, group=sample),position=position_dodge(width=1.5), width=1.5,size=1, colour="red") +
    geom_point(data= filter(all_data_summ1, different == "yes"), colour="black", size=8,stroke=2, aes(rep_n,mean,group=sample),position=position_dodge(width=1.5), shape=0) + 
    geom_point(position=position_dodge(width=1.5), size=4, pch=21, aes(fill=sample)) +
    scale_x_continuous(breaks = rep_sequence) +
    labs(x="Replication", y="Average", title= paste0('Sample Means with 95% Confidence Interval Bars at CV=',cv, '%')) +
    theme_gray(base_size = 25) +
    theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) 

}

print(table(record_test)/length(record_test))
```